# Warning: A rendering was not used on the page. The placeholder "xxxxxx" was not found

Tags: presentation, caching

There is a Desktop Layout (Desktop.aspx) with several controls (Figure 1 and Figure 3). One of the controls called "Two Column Big Left" (TwoColumnBigLeft.ascx) has three placeholders (Inner Content Top, Left, Right). Then, there are six controls added to the three placeholders on the "Two Column Big Left" control.

```
Page Title (Inner Content Top)
Generic Body Content (Left)
Video Carousel (Left)
Capability Accordian (Left)
Generic Callout (Right)
Generic Callout (Right)
```

I am getting warnings in Debug mode (Figure 2) and caching is not working correctly (it is supposed to vary by data on the "Playbook Playlist" control, but it is cached permanently).

Is this considered a correct way to configure the Presentation Details? What do I need to do to get rid of the warnings? Do the placeholders all need to be on Desktop.aspx? Or, maybe the TwoColumnBigLeft.ascx page needs to be included on the Desktop.aspx page directly in the code (not through Sitecore presentation details)? Should I create a second version of the Desktop.aspx page to use for this page?

Other than the caching problem, the page looks fine in the web browser.

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]

**Figure 3**

[image]

Comment: did you make any upgrade to 8.1 ? can you try to remove temporary html cache and check if the warning appear?

Comment: No, I did not upgrade to 8.1.

Comment: Can you click the "Edit" button in Presentation Details (the one in youre Figure 1 screenshot), and take a screenshot of the resulting dialog? The difference is that the resulting dialog displays the names of the placeholder that each rendering is being added to, and this will help us in debugging your issue.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel See Figure 3, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the Desktop.aspx and the TwoColumnBigLeft.ascx files?  If not the whole files, can you provide the sections of the files that show all.ofnthe placeholders in question?  Also, are you seeing this issue in Experience Editor?  If not, could it be that you simply need to publish all of the items you recemtly created?

Comment: Did you try adding the placeholder settings? It looks like system is verifying the placeholder key you used for renderings is available from list of placeholder controls added to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an entry for this in the [Sitecore presentation component troubleshooting guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/presentation_component_troubleshooting_sc60-64-a4.pdf)

It's this section:

> If layout details indicate that the layout engine should bind a
> control to a placeholder, but the layout engine cannot locate a
> placeholder with that key in the layouts and sublayouts already
> processed, the layout engine does not create an error visible to the
> browser. Instead, the layout engine writes warning messages such as
> the following to the page trace visible in the Sitecore browser-based
> debugger:
>
> Warning
>
> A rendering was not used on the page
>
> The placeholder was not found
>
> If you locate any of these warning messages in the page
> trace, confirm that the sublayouts and renderings in layout details
> for the item specify placeholder keys that exist in the layout and
> sublayouts specified. Ensure that placeholder settings list controls
> in component nesting order. For example, a sublayout containing a
> placeholder should appear before the controls that bind to that
> placeholder. Ensure that fully qualified placeholder keys reflect the
> correct placeholder nesting order.

It sounds like this is a common issue - if you look in your placeholder settings, check that you have the correct placeholder controls and that they are in nested order (so make sure your 3 inner placeholders are below their parent placeholder).

If that isn't what's wrong - you could also try using fully qualified placeholder names (e.g. instead of "Right" use "/Content/Right").

Comment: The three inner placeholders are below their parent placeholder. I will try the fully qualified placeholder name when I get a chance.

Comment: Cool, also might be worth adding your "Placeholder Settings" screenshot to your question and also the code defining the placeholders. I've always used lower case with hyphens and no spaces for placeholder names (e.g. "inner-content-top"), I'm not aware of any issue with cases and spaces in placeholder names but might also be worth a try when you get a mo.

Comment: Fully qualified placeholder names got rid of the warnings.

Comment: Just a note, since I just hit the same issue after an upgrade, the placeholder you are being warned about may fail even with a fully qualified placeholder name if the parent placeholder is also not fully qualified. So, make sure all the steps down have the full path if you start seeing these warnings and want to get rid of them!